# Open a local HTML file in Full screen in IE without showing a security prompt

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, fullscreen

We have developed an offline HTML application - basically a collection of HTML pages with some JS and CSS resources (external files that are referenced in HTML page) to support it.

To run this app, all the client (customer) needs to do is to just open the "*LandingPage.html*" file in his IE Browser (client will only be using IE).

Recently the client asked for the application to be designed such that it automatically opens in full screen mode. So they don't want to be asked to press F11.

We implemented this using the many different JavaScript solutions available - but all of them use ActiveX / cause the security prompt to appear which the user has to acknowledge.

We cannot recommend the user to go and change the IE Security settings related to Active X Objects / Scripts / Initialization etc - that suggestion isn't well received.

The client wants the application to open in full screen -

1. Without showing any prompt / asking for acknowledgement
2. It should be automatic / it should not require user to press F11 or any other button.
3. They don't want the page to be opened in another window (we demo-ed the `window.open` solution too ... ) either.

**Any suggestions to achieve this functionality?**  I know there are too many constraints ...

Comment: Is [HTA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) an option?

Comment: Hi Dr.Molle - I went through the documentation for HTA and I can get a feel for the advantages this would have given us - had we gone down that path earlier. Thank you - this was really useful - food for thought for next time...

I tried to apply the HTA model to our existing app and a lot of JS errors started throwing up.
We are close to UAT so its not possible to remodel entirely - we need to to find a solution within the current setup.

Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a Launcher for the IE  (may be some script or a HTA-file as well)

Example-HTA:

```
<html>
<head>
 <hta:application 
 showintaskbar="no"
 singleinstance="yes"
 sysmenu="no"
 windowstate="minimize"
 >
 <script>
 IE = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application") ;   
 IE.Visible = 1 ;
 IE.navigate( "file://C:/path/to/LandingPage.html" ) ;
 IE.TheaterMode=true;
 //close HTA
 self.close();
 </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

When you want to use it as script copy the first 4 lines  of the `<script/>` into a file with the ending `.js`

Comment: I created a HTA launcher using same example as above but that still creates the ActiveX prompt in IE as shown in image below :

http://tinypic.com/r/mtqy5t/8

Comment: Did you give it the ending .hta ?

Comment: Yup. It's identical to your code sample above except for the path.

Comment: By default a HTA-file should be opened with the HTA-host and not with IE, the HTA-host shouldn't force a prompt with the heading "Internet Explorer", because it's not IE(it shouldn't force a security-prompt at all, of course HTA is insecure ). Are you sure  that the .hta-file has been opened via the HTA-host

Comment: Hi,
When I double click the launcher HTA I created, it opens in the HTA-host (because I can see a dialog window - greyed out, for a fraction of a second, and then it closes itself -self.close()? ) and then IE opens with the prompt....

Comment: Do you get the prompt also when you use a URL for navigate like e.g. "http://stackoverflow.com" ...when not, there must be insecure content inside the LandingPage.html . Which windows-version do you use?

Comment: Update :
No prompt for URLs. The prompt shown now is the "Internet Explorer restricted this page from running scripts / active X .... "

 This is because I am running an HTML page locally and I guess I possibly can't avoid this first prompt.

Marking @Dr.Molle's original reply as answer - thank you !